# gives error on find_first_of function with binary predicate

Tags: c++, stl, predicate

Here is the code

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class test {
    struct con {
        string s1;
        string s2;
    };
public:
    void somefunc();

private:
    bool pred(con c1, con c2);
    vector<con> vec;
};

void test::somefunc()
{
    vector<con> v;
    vector<con>::iterator it = find_first_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), v.begin(), v.end(), pred);
}

bool test::pred(con c1, con c2)
{
    return 0;
}
```

it gives error

est.cpp(24) : error C2664: 'struct test::con *__cdecl std::find_first_of(struct test::con *,struct test::con *,struct test::con *,struct test::con *,bool (__thiscall *)(struct test::con,str
uct test::con))' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'bool (struct test::con,struct test::con)' to 'bool (__thiscall *)(struct test::con,struct test::con)'
        None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type

I don't understand what is (__thiscall*) and how to convert my predicate function to it.

Comment: Member function pointers are not the same as function pointers. You can't reasonably convert them.

Answer (score 2):

Your predicate cannot be a non-static member function, since this takes an implicit first parameter, giving a total of three parameters. You need either a static member function, or a non-member:

```
// non-member function
bool pred(const con& c1, const con& c2)
{
    return false;
}

void test::somefunc()
{
  vector<con> v;
  vector<con>::iterator it = find_first_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                                           v.begin(), v.end(), 
                                           pred);
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::bind` to bind `this` as the first parameter:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
vector<con>::iterator it = find_first_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
                                         v.begin(), v.end(),
                                         std::bind(&test::pred, this, _1, _2));
```

The call to `std::bind` produces a callable entity with with two `con` parameters. It stores a copy of the `this` pointer internally (but `this` isn't used in your `pred` function).

Answer (score 1):

`__thiscall` is a calling convention which is used for *non-static* member function only by MSVC++.

In your code, `pred` is a *non-static* member function, which cannot be used as binary-predicate without some workaround such as `std::bind`. I would rather suggest you to make this function `static`. Or even better use [lamda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) (C++11 only).

Answer (score 0):

Your predicate is a *non-static* member function. Either make it static (or simply a non-member function), or use `std::bind()` (or the equivalent Boost.Bind if you can't afford C++11):

```
#include <functional>

// ...

vector<con>::iterator it = find_first_of(
    vec.begin(), vec.end(), v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::bind(&test::pred, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ec462f91ddd116ef8ceff283739226b3-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

If you choose to keep your function as a member function and use `std::bind()`, consider qualifying your function `pred()` as `const`, since it is likely *not* supposed to alter the state of the object it is invoked on.